# A long cloth which fans hold up in stadiums

Tags: word-request

If you're a soccer fan you probably have seen fans holding some kind of long cloth sometimes with the team coat of arms while cheering their favourite team. It pretty much looks like a scarf but it's sometimes very thin, so I'm not sure if it can be called that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a Google search, they are called soccer scarves.

Here's a quote from [an article I found about it](http://www.scarves.net/blog/soccer-scarves-the-ultimate-accessory):

> Team scarves first appeared in Britain in the early 1900s. They were designed to allow fans to stay warm in the winter without sacrificing their team spirit. The original soccer scarves were striped, alternating the team’s colors. This style is still the most popular in the UK and Australia. Then came the addition of the club crest and team name, followed by scarves decorated with team slogans and pictures of popular players. Now the possibilities are endless. Scarves are made for important matches, championships and rivalries.

Comment: Huh! I should've searched soccer scarves instead of 'fans holding up scarves.' Thanks.

Comment: They are real scarves: quite thick, knitted and made with wool (or wool substitute) They are quite functional: you can wrap one around your neck to keep warm. Football is a winter sport in Europe, and football stadiums get cold!